# Lua: String to name?

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

is it possible to convert a string into a name of a table entry? 
just like

```
string = "test"
y = {test = 123}
print y.string
```

So if string is "test" it would print y.test if there is such a entry
Hope you understand my question!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you read [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) first?

Comment: That's actually what the `table.name` syntax _does_ - it's just a shorthand for `table["name"]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
print(y[string])
```

Be careful with using names such as string for variables, especially globals. You've just overwritten the string table.

Comment: You probably meant `print(y[string])`.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko of course. I was typing from my mobile.